# Updating records in access with a timestamp once a certain threshold is reached

Tags: ms-access

My apologies, I am a bit of a novice in access and I can't seem to find the solution for the below:

I have a simple access database for monitoring the number of hours spent on a task. At the point that this activity exceeds 7 hours I would like for the record to be updated to signify this fact, possibly with a time stamp indicating the month and year in which this was exceeded.

The information regarding hours spent on the task would be manually entered on a single given day of the month, and the 7+ hours can be collected over a number of months. It is however necessary to be able to produce reports from the data with breakdowns indicating how many tasks exceeded the 7 hours, and on which month did this happen.

How do I set that automated rule/action to update the record on the 7 hours threshold? (Each record currently contains a single field with a running total of hours recorded)

Comment: I don't know your project type.  This could be a match.   http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-trigger-adp-HP003085415.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways that you can do this if you are using a Form to insert new records into your table. It would also help if you have some knowledge of VBA

If you are are using MS Access 2013, you could also use Data Macros (MS Access equivalence of SQL Server triggers).

Assuming that you are using a lower version of Access and assuming that you are using a Form to insert/update Data into your table, the following could be done:

```
1. Create a query that summarize all hours spent group by taskID (*SELECT TaskID, SUM(Task_Hours) AS TotalHours FROM Tasks GROUP BY TaskID*  let call this Query TasksTotals)
2. Modify your Tasks table to Include Date/Time you can call it TaskDate) and another field called SeventhHourReached with a Boolean or a text value to be Yes or No
3. Create another Query that filters all tasks that have already reached the 7th hours (SELECT TaskID FROM Tasks Where SevethHourdReached ="Yes" GROUP by TaskID) - Lets call this query Tasks7H
```

Now you will need to do some VAB

Of your Form's ***Current*** Event procedure or on your form field hours ***After Update***
use the following event procedure in VBA

```
If DLookup("TotalHours", "TasksTotals", "TaskID = " & Me.TaskID &"") >= 7 Then
  If DLookup("TaskID", "Tasks7h", "TaskID = " Me.TaskID & "") <> Me.TaskID Then
  Me.SevethHoursReached = "Yes" ----- This is you used a text field
  End If
End if
```

Make sure the field SevethHourReached shows on your Form but disabled or locked or disabled and locked.

For you reports, you will have the date and time when the seveth hour was reached if you just used the function now() for the default value on your TaskDate field.  You can filter all the records which have the sevethhourreached as yes for your report query.